# IF conditions - content for specific users only

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Hello I am new in cakephp 1.3 and i have problem in if condition.I really need help. I want to post a message for specific user.Only user can open the message according to their course. The admin can view it all but when i log-in as user it doesn't show any message.

Here are my code:

```
<?php if ($current_user['id'] == $message['Course']['id']): ?>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link($message['Course']['course'], array('controller' => 'courses', 'action' => 'view', $message['Course']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $message['Batch']['batch']; ?>
    </td> 
    <td><?php echo $message['Message']['title']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $message['Message']['message']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $message['Message']['created']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You're comparing the `$current_user['id']` to the Course ID - shouldn't you be comparing the current user's Course ID to the Course ID?

Comment: Where did you get your $message['Course']['id'] or can you show us more of your codes?

Comment: replace this line <?php if ($current_user['id'] == $message['Course']['id']): ?> with <?php echo "<pre>";print_r($message);echo "</pre>"; if ($current_user['id'] == $message['Course']['id']): ?> and share the output.

Comment: Array
(
    [Message] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [user_id] => 2
            [course_id] => 2
            [batch_id] => 6
            [title] => hahahahaha
            [message] => wheeeeeeeeeeeeeee
            [created] => 2014-02-03 22:19:13
        )

Comment: [Course] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [course] => BSCrim
            [course_name] => Bachelor of Science in Criminology
            [department_id] => 2
        )

    [Batch] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [batch] => Batch 2014
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `user_id` column in your courses table, then try to use the following and share the result:

```
<?php if ($current_user['id'] == $message['Course']['user_id']): ?>
<td>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link($message['Course']['course'], array('controller' => 'courses', 'action' => 'view', $message['Course']['id'])); ?>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $message['Batch']['batch']; ?>
</td> 
<td><?php echo $message['Message']['title']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
<td><?php echo $message['Message']['message']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
<td><?php echo $message['Message']['created']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: The course_id is in my users table..How should do this in if condition?

Comment: if($current_user['course_id'] == $message['Course']['id'])... else remain the same.

Comment: It display all the post message for user and admin.The massage should be display only for specific user according to their course id..